# Navigate only when state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have one array in which I am adding items using setState() now at certain conditions I want to move to another screen but only after item added in the array. All items are getting added successfully but when that one condition becomes true it is getting redirect to the next screen before updating the state.

Adding items in array :

```
   setAnswers(prevState => ([...prevState, { question: question, answers: answer,selectedAnswer:item, action: action }]))
```

Condition when i want to redirect :

```
 if (answerStore[item].endpoint) {
  navigation.navigate("InjurySummary", { answers: answers, endpoint: answerStore[item].endpoint })
                                 }
```

Now because of this last item of the array not getting added as it moves to the next screen so fast. Is there any way to redirect to the next screen after the state updated.

Note: I am using functional component

Comment: Where do you have the navigate code ? inside useEffect ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` hook, which will encounter each time when your state update.

```
  useEffect(() => {
  // write your logic here,if you want to perfom any task when answers updated
  }, [answers])
```

`useEffect` hook has 2 arguments, first is a callback function and second is dependency array which will keep watching your dependency and encounter when dependency update.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use setTimeout, I believe that use useEffect to update a state is not consider a good practice !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).